# Can I have an send message task before a Gateway in BPMN?

Tags: diagram, bpmn, processmodel, flow-diagram

I have a BPMN diagram and I have a send message task connect to a gateway.
Is this allowed? If not how can I solve it?
The behavior I want to achieve is inform about the beginning of a process ( send message task) to two different lanes ( the two receive message tasks).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's a perfectly valid diagram/flow.